# como subir cambios a git hub sin tener que bajar los cambios nuevos en la rama?

Tags: git, github

soy nuevo con el uso de git y github, el problema es el siguiente, trabajamos en el proyecto de la carrera, lo que pasa es que hicimos desde git hub un **pull request** a la rama de uno de mis compañeros, pero el no bajo esos cambios y siguió trabajando con lo que tenia en ese momento de manera local, ahora el problema es que cuando el trata de subir los cambios que el hizo en el proyecto, git se lo niega por que como ha bajado los cambios nuevos de su rama, la incógnita es la siguiente, hay alguna manera de poder subir esos cambios a git hub, o de poder bajar los cambios y que no se borren los cambios que el ya hizo?? nosotros normalmente bajamos los cambios con **git pull**, lo cual hace que sobrescriba lo que esta de manera local por mas que el **commit** ya este hecho.

Gracias de ante mano por la ayuda que me puedan brindar... saludos de un estudiante en problemas desde CR

Comment: un `git pull` no debe sobreescribir cambios que se hicieron en otra rama.... por lo menos de buenas a primera... seguro hay flujos que pueden generar ese comportamiento, pero no van a ser los flujos simplones donde se trabaja en cosas diferentes en diferentes ramas y se quiere mezclar los cambios. Lo que debería suceder si alguien hizo unos cambios y en otra rama se modifica esa misma sección de código es que se debe presentar un conflicto... a menos que le metas opciones a git para que agarre una de las dos versiones si hay un conflicto.... en ese caso, qué puede hacer git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> nosotros normalmente bajamos los cambios con git pull, lo cual hace que sobrescriba lo que esta de manera local por mas que el commit ya este hecho.

Eso es incorrecto. Si localmente ya está hecho un commit un git pull no lo va a sobreescribir de ninguna manera.

Volviendo a tu pregunta:

El proceso para sincronizar es hacer commit localmente y luego ejecutar el comando `git pull` y resolver los posibles conflictos que se den.

Comment: muchas gracias voy a comentarle a mi comañero para que haga el proceso